# How do you write (9.5*(4.5)-2.5*3)/(45.5-3.5) in Java?

Tags: java, math, expression

How do you write (9.5*(4.5)-2.5*3)/(45.5-3.5) in Java?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework type questions should include a best good faith attempt to solve the problem. Also this looks to be extremely basic Java, and would be best answered by perusing most any intro to Java tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Write:

```
(9.5*(4.5)-2.5*3)/(45.5-3.5)`
```

Writing a mathematical expression in Java would be the **same** as writing it in algebra, as Java follows *Order of Operations*.